# Warmup exercises before running

Tags: running, warm-up

I am a college student and regularly run ~2k (5 rounds of standard athletic track) everyday (Although, regularity gets broken around the time of examinations or submissions for as long as a month). So, whenever I try to restart the streak of running, my body tends to become stiff and probably due to improper warmup, after first day running, I usually face unbearable body aches. This makes doing routine jobs too painstaking for me. This phenomena is usually sorted after a week or so; after which it becomes okay to run without much of an issue.

So, are there any recommendations over some warmup excercises and/or dietary plan which I must follow to prevent such pain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If weather is worm you can walk for about 15 min after the training. That slow down allows better regeneration.

Also rolling legs after training can be beneficial.

If you plan to stretch before training - do short, dynamic stretching, which prepares for the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, well done for attempting to maintain a regular running routine!

I think most people these days favour dynamic stretching and drills for a warm up. You could try doing :

- 30secs of leg lifts on each leg
- 6 x 100m strides getting progressively quicker